# Jquery: How to get a href link and go click/activate that link in a tabber

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation

We already have a tabber done is jquery with this html code

Navigation

```
 <ul class="tabber">
          <li><a href="#tab1">...</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#tab2">...</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#tab3"..</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside><!-- end aside-->
```

Content

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <div class="products">
    <h6><a href="#tab1">...</a></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
    <h6><a href="#tab2">...</a></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
    <h6><a href="#tab3">...</a></h6>
  </div>    
</div><!-- end tab content 1 -->

<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  ...
</div><!-- end tab content 2 -->

<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
  ...
</div><!-- end tab content 3 -->
```

The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //Default Action
    $('.tab_content').hide(); //Hide all content
    $('ul.tabber li:first').addClass('active').show(); //Activate first tab
    $('.tab_content:first').show(); //Show first tab content    
    //On Click Event
    $('ul.tabber li').click(function() {
        $('ul.tabber li').removeClass('active'); //Remove any 'active' class
        $(this).addClass('active'); //Add 'active' class to selected tab
        $('.tab_content').hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
});
```

we want the copy the href link then would jquery would someone like would click our navigation

Comment: Why dont you just use the jquery UI tabs?

Comment: also, your question doesn't really make sense...

Comment: <snip> we want the copy the href link then would jquery would someone like would click our navigation </snip> Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry guys, I will try to rephrase my question later. I'm a little in in a hurry right now.

Comment: Do you want to load an iframe or frame when someone clicks on one of the tabs..? Something like this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/

Comment: this is a jquery tabber with html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant understand you but maybe you want use links like /mypage#tab1,/mypage#tab2...?

Comment: what i meant was `<h6><a href="#tab1">...</a></h6>` should work like our <a> on our navigation link `<ul class="tabber">`

Comment: Oh, ****. You have tab header (titles) and tab content. Did you mean what you want to use <h6>...</h6> for switch to another tab (like in tab header)?

Comment: You can handle tab links same as in tab header. For example, you can use same class in content links and tab header links and write handler for this class for switching tab